# Unity3D - Third Person Player movement in diagonal direction is slower than vertical and horizontal movement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a character controller that allows the movement speed to be affected by how far the player is pressing the left stick. When I *can* get that much to work, the other issue I encounter is the players speed decreasing while moving diagonally.

Most of the information I've found online deal with the opposite issue where diagonal movement is faster (movement vector goes above 1). The solution there would be to clamp the magnitude so pressing the stick into a corner doesn't go above 1. I've tried clamping to see if that would work, however, I don't believe that's the solution to my problem.

The code here allows the player to move in relation to the camera and the speed is influenced by input vector.

```cs
Vector3 input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
Vector3 inputDir = input.normalized;
```

```cs
void Move(Vector3 inputDir, Vector3 input)
    {
        running = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Joystick1Button1); // B button on xbox one controller

        // Rotation stuff
        if (inputDir != Vector3.zero) {
            float targetRotation = Mathf.Atan2(inputDir.x, inputDir.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cameraTransform.eulerAngles.y;
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.up * Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetRotation, ref turnSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(speedSmoothTime));
        }

        // Pretty sure this is where things are breaking        
        float targetSpeed = ((running) ? runSpeed : walkSpeed) * inputDir.magnitude;
        currentSpeed = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentSpeed, targetSpeed, ref speedSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(speedSmoothTime));
        currentSpeed *= input.magnitude;
        vel = transform.forward * currentSpeed + Vector3.up * velocityY;
        currentSpeed = new Vector3(_controller.velocity.x, 0, _controller.velocity.z).magnitude;
    }
```

```cs
void ExecuteMovement()
    {            
        _controller.Move(vel * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Comment: inputDir.magnitude is always zero or 1 (in targetSpeed).. Did you perhaps mean to set your target speed to input.magnitude (clamped to 1)?

Comment: That said, why are you multiplying currentSpeed by input.magnitude? you already adjusted for it with your smoothdamp.

Comment: You also don't need the last set to currentspeed, as that should give you the same value

Comment: If, for some reason, your `input.magnitude` isn't returning 1 when going diagonal (stick calibration issue), then with your current system, you'd end up with reduced speed. What value do you get for `input.magnitude` if you go UP-RIGHT 45 degrees full power?

Comment: @Mars after a lot of testing I found out it was my xbox controller that was giving me issues. I just assumed it was my code through hours of trying to fix this issue. However, I did adjust my code and get rid of unnecessary or redundant things thanks to your suggestions!